# Realm - Sum all fields error

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Im trying to get all of the duration fields from my object and add them together however I cannot seem to find a solution to do this.

My object is as follows:

```
Results<Relax> <0x7fe6f1c61bf0> (
    [0] Relax {
        relax = New Activity;
        duration = 16.000000;
        time = 7:05 PM;
        date = 3/18/18;
    },
    [1] Relax {
        relax = New Activity;
        duration = 1.000000;
        time = 7:12 PM;
        date = 3/18/18;
    },
    [2] Relax {
        relax = New Activity;
        duration = 1.000000;
        time = 7:18 PM;
        date = 3/18/18;
    },
    [3] Relax {
        relax = New Activity;
        duration = 3.000000;
        time = 7:31 PM;
        date = 3/18/18;
    },
    [4] Relax {
        relax = New Activity;
        duration = 3.000000;
        time = 7:32 PM;
        date = 3/18/18;
    },
    [5] Relax {
        relax = New Activity;
        duration = 5.000000;
        time = 8:55 PM;
        date = 3/18/18;
    }
)
```

So for example if you add all of these durations together you should get 29

I have tried the following:

```
    func getAllTime(){
     let allTime = realm.objects(Relax.self).sum(ofProperty: "duration")
        print(allTime)
    }
```

but this error appears in the code:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

My Realm Object is configured as follows:

```
@objcMembers class Relax: Object {


    dynamic var relax: String = ""
    dynamic var duration: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var time: String = ""
    dynamic var date: String = ""

    convenience init(relax: String, duration: Double, time: String, date: String) {
        self.init()
        self.relax = relax
        self.duration = duration
        self.time = time
        self.date = date
    }

}
```

I is there any way to fix this or another way around this error?

I'm fairly new to Swift and Realm and cant really work out why this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic function the compiler error is referring to is `sum(ofProperty:)`. This can be seen by looking at the type signature of the function, which is `func sum<T>(ofProperty property: String) -> T where T : AddableType`.

If you add explicit type annotation to the `allTime` variable, the error is solved.

```
let allTime: Double = realm.objects(Relax.self).sum(ofProperty: "duration")
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much!